# Problem with RegionNearest?

Tags: regions, syntax, nearest

Consider the following region:

```
reg = BooleanRegion[#1 &&  ! #2 & , {Parallelepiped[{-3.24, -2.415, 
    9.2}, {{6.48, 0, 0}, {0, 4.83, 0}, {0, 0, 
     0.20000000000000012}}], 
     Cylinder[{{0., 0., 9.2}, {0., 0., 9.4}}, 0.09]}]
```

I would like to find the closest point belonging to the region relative to the origin {0,0,0}. I use `RegionNearest`:

```
RegionNearest[reg, {0, 0, 0}]
```

However, it gets stuck:

```
TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit]
```

How to avoid this problem? Does it appear because there is a degeneracy at the boundary of the cylinder?

P.S. I know that I may simply use the explicit expression for `reg` and conclude that the closest point is, say, `{0.09,0,9.2}`. I rather want to make the procedure automatic.

Comment: `RegionNearest[DiscretizeRegion@reg, {0, 0, 0}]` gives `{0., 0., 9.2}` in version  "14.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

Comment: @kglr : but this point does not belong to `reg`. So maybe decreasing `MaxCellMeasure` would help?

Comment: @kglr : even if setting extra small volume `MaxCellMeasure -> "Volume" -> 0.00001`, it does not recover the point properly, still returning a point outside `reg`. If setting smaller, it gets stuck.

Answer (score 6):

Try `RegionDifference` instead of `BooleanRegion` and rationalize the input

```
epi = Apply[Parallelepiped, {{-3.24, -2.415,9.2}, {{6.48, 0, 0}, {0, 4.83,0}, {0, 0, 0.200000000000000 }}} //Rationalize[#, 0] &]
cyl = Apply[Cylinder, {{{0., 0., 9.2}, {0., 0., 9.4}} , 0.09} //Rationalize[#, 0] &]
reg = RegionDifference[epi, cyl]

RegionNearest[reg, {0, 0, 0}] (*{-(9/100), 0, 46/5}*)
RegionDistance[reg, %]        (*0*)
```